# Limits to NFS share sizes

Tags: apache-2.2, vmware-esx, nfs, redhat

I want to build a bare-metal RHEL box connected to an FC-array that's presenting it a ~16TB LUN, I can format this LUN any way I like (might choose XFS) but I then want to share this volume out to a number of Apache web-serving RHEL VMs running on ESX 3.5/4 via NFS. Are there any limits to the size of an NFS mount in this range (or possibly slightly larger) that'll get in my way?

I'm a few weeks from being able to test this but will post the answer then if nobody knows right now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - just make sure you use NFSv3 or higher on the client to mount it. (v3 has been around for a long time though so no major issues there). NFSv2 had some filesystem size reporting funniness with larger filesystems.

We run XFS on NFS servers much bigger than 16TB and everything works just fine.